# C# and libharu: using TTF-Fonts

Tags: c#, truetype, libharu

I'm trying to use TTF-Fonts within libharu.

```
string arialtmp = doc.LoadTTFontFromFile("c:\\windows\\fonts\\ariali.ttf", true);
HPdfFont arial2 = doc.GetFont(arialtmp, "CP1250");

page.SetFontAndSize(arial2, 25);
page.BeginText();
page.MoveTextPos(50, 650);
page.ShowText("bla blaa!!");
page.EndText();
```

But libharu don't use ariali.ttf . I'm getting no compile error or anything else, libharu just don't use the font. I can also write damn.ttf and get the same result.

So what's wrong?

I'm using libharu with c# interface and Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Does the account running the application have permissions to read from that file location? Did you try copying the file to the program directory and loading it from there?

Comment: Are arialtmp and arial2 non-null at runtime? You wouldn't get a compile error.

Comment: @Oded: yes, it runs as admin. I'm using csc and VS command prompt to compile the file and mistyped the output file. So I executed the old EXE file again and again, how stupid is that. Thanks Oded and Rup for your help. Problem is "fixed"